# The Meaning of "Crew Expendable"?

Tags: meaning, expressions

In a game (Call of Duty 4: Modern Warfare), when a soldier (Gaz) asks his commander (Captain Price) about the "rules of engagement," he is answered "crew expendable."

As they are fighting on a ship, I have two translations in mind:

1. The ship crew (the enemy) are expendable; i.e. you can kill whomever you want.
2. The team crew are expendable; i.e. the team should fulfill their objective, even at the cost of their lives.

Which translation is right?

Comment: The terminology has no set meaning, and is dependent on context and the established jargon of the setting.

Comment: Teams don't really have crews. Team, squad, crew are similar terms. Whereas a manned ship always has a crew, but not a team or squad, in the normal parlance. Also, I'm not sure if an order for a team or squad to take casualties would be worded as 'team/squad expendable'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you read the [wiki on Call of Duty](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Crew_Expendable), definitely the former: the ship crew can be engaged.

[image]

The [trivia on that episode](http://callofduty.wikia.com/wiki/Crew_Expendable/Trivia) also include:

> This mission contains many references to the Aliens series of films: **These include the title, "Crew Expendable" (in reference to a line from the first film)**, and the lines "I like to keep this for close encounters", "Check those corners", "Stay Frosty" and "Soldier, we are leaving".

From [imdb on Aliens](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0078748/synopsis)

> Ripley queries Mother for advice on destroying the alien, but in the process discovers that "**the company**" (unnamed in this film, but identified in the sequels as Weyland-Yutani) had recognized the signal as a warning and **wanted one of the alien creatures brought back for study, considering the crew expendable**.

Comment: Note the "Weapons free" in the picture: Weapons can fire at any target not positively identified as friendly. This is the least restrictive weapon control status.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Very informative; I learnt much more than I expected!

Comment: Expendable means the ship crew can be engaged and *killed*.

Comment: Yes, but  in the movie, the *crew* is not the enemy. So *crew expendable* doesn't really mean the same thing.

Comment: @Clare I agree. In the movie, the latter meaning would apply. Although a crew member "infected" could be considered as enemy ;)